# `this` becomes window in super constructor even using `bind`

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript. When I did some objective oriented programming, I want to invoke constructor of super class in a sub-class:

```
function P(p1, p2) {
  alert(this);
  this.v1 = p1;
  this.v2 = p2;
}

var middleObj = function() {};
middleObj.prototype = P.prototype;

var C = function(p1, p2) {
    P.bind(this, p1, p2);
    P();
}
C.prototype = new middleObj();
C.prototype.constructor = C;

var objChild = new C(1,2);
alert(objChild instanceof P);
alert(objChild.v2);
```

If I call P() directly in C(), this turns to `window`, and I can understand that. However, even if I bind this to C(), still I can not get the proper value of `this`. As a result, the second alert will show undefined because v2 is not initialized properly.

Comment: If you look more closely at the answers in the linked dupetarget, you'll see that they always use the return value of `bind` (and they explain why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`P.bind()` will return a function, you need to assign it to your `P` again. Like this

```
 P = P.bind(this, p1, p2)
```

But in this case I suggest you to use just `P.call(this, p1, p2);`

```js
function P(p1, p2) {
  alert(this);
  this.v1 = p1;
  this.v2 = p2;
}

var middleObj = function() {};
middleObj.prototype = P.prototype;

var C = function(p1, p2) {
    P.call(this, p1, p2);
}
C.prototype = new middleObj();
C.prototype.constructor = C;

var objChild = new C(1,2);
alert(objChild instanceof P);
alert(objChild.v2);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It is solved